# CRON expression to start every 9th of month excluding weekend

Tags: cron

I have to schedule a job to run every 9th of the month. and if 9th falls in weekend then in should run on next monday

for example 
feb 9th is sunday so it should run on feb 10th i.e. next working day.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of logic won't be possible entirely from your crontab schedule. I'll also point out the possibility that Monday might **not** necessarily be the "next working day" (think of holidays for example) in which case you might want to account for that as well.

If you will *always* choose Monday when the 9th is on a weekend (regardless of that Monday being a *real working day*, you can schedule your cron job to run on the 9th, 10th, and 11th of every month. For example, this would run on the **9th/10th/11th at 8am** every month:

`* 8 9-11 * 0  your_script`

After that, the logic to determine if tasks need to run will have to be handled within the script itself. If you're using Python for example:

```py
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
weekday = today.weekday()

if weekday is 5 or weekday is 6:
    print("it's the weekend, do nothing")
elif today.day is 9 or (today.day is not 9 and weekday is 0):
    print("run the script on the 9th or the first Monday after the 9th")
else:
    print("this should not happen")
```

(Note that the script would run on every single Monday with this logic, but if you set up the cron job only to run on the 9th/10th/11th of the month then it will work just fine)

I really hope this helps!